# How is it possible to sort nested map by keys?

Tags: clojure

This

```clj
{0 {:data {7 2, 0 1, 3 4}}, 1 {:data {2 3, 1 1, 0 0}}}
```

should be sorted like this

```clj
{0 {:data {0 1, 3 4, 7 2}}, 1 {:data {0 0, 1 1, 2 3}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a sorted map e.g.

```clj
(defn- sort-map [m]
  (into (sorted-map) m))

(defn sort-data [m]
  (->> m
       (map (fn [[k v]] [k (update v :data sort-map)]))
       (into {})))
```

then

```
(sort-data {0 {:data {7 2, 0 1, 3 4}}, 1 {:data {2 3, 1 1, 0 0}}})
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a function `unlazy` that I use for converting data into a canonical form.  It recursively walks any data structure, converting all sequential types into vectors, and all maps/sets into sorted versions.  It also converts native Java types into the Clojure equivalent:

```
(defn unlazy
  "Converts a lazy collection to a concrete (eager) collection of the same type."
  [coll]
  (let [unlazy-item (fn [item]
                      (cond
                        (sequential? item) (vec item)

            #?@(:clj  [ (map? item) (into (sorted-map-generic) item)
                        (set? item) (into (sorted-set-generic) item) ]
                :cljs [ (map? item) (into (sorted-map) item) ; #todo => (sorted-map-generic)
                        (set? item) (into (sorted-set) item) ; #todo => (sorted-map-generic)
                      ] )

            #?@(:clj [
                        (instance? java.io.InputStream item) (slurp item)  ; #todo need test
                        (instance? java.util.List item) (vec item)  ; #todo need test
                        (instance? java.util.Map item) (into {} item)  ; #todo need test
                        (instance? java.lang.Iterable item) (into [] item)  ; #todo need test
                     ])
                        :else item))
        result    (walk/prewalk unlazy-item coll) ]
    result))
```

For a simple case, it could be reduced like so:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(defn walk-sorted
  [coll]
  (let [sort-item   (fn [item]
                      (cond    
                        (map? item) (into (sorted-map) item)
                        (set? item) (into (sorted-set) item) ]
                        :else item)) ]
      (walk/prewalk sort-item coll)))  ; or postwalk
```

Please note that sorted maps/sets are only useful for printing in a nice format (to make reading easier). Otherwise, it won't affect the way your program runs.

For advanced purposes, you may wish to explore [the `clojure.data.avl` library](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) and [the API docs](https://cljdoc.org/d/org.clojure/data.avl/0.1.0/doc/readme).

Answer (score 3):

here I go, promoting [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter) again! (as if it needs any promotion):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer [transform MAP-VALS]])

(transform [MAP-VALS :data] #(into (sorted-map) %) data)
;;=> {0 {:data {0 1, 3 4, 7 2}}, 1 {:data {0 0, 1 1, 2 3}}}
```

Comment: Good library at first sight, I need to look at it more detailed